# IBM MobileFirst Quality Assurance 6.3 integration with Rational Team Concert is not working for IBM DevOps Service

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

I have been using Worklight Quality Assurance(WQA) (renamed as IBM MobileFirst Platform Quality Assurance in 6.3 release) and had set up the Rational Team Concert to automatically create work item for bugs and crashes. In my RTC setup, I had used IBM DevOps service project (JazzHub) for automatic creation of work time for the bugs and crashes reported from the instrumented application. This integration has stopped working after I update to WQA 6.3 (IBM MobileFirst Platform Quality Assurance 6.3)

Answer (score 0):

With IBM MobileFirst Platform Quality Assurance 6.3, if you are integrating with IBM DevOps service project for work item creation for bugs and crashes, then in the Rational Team Concert setup page, you need to provide the Jazz ID for the username and password of the IBM ID that is linked to the Jazz ID for the password for the authentication to work.

For earlier version of WQA, the integration with IBM DevOps service project used to work with JazzID and Jazz Password. If you had already setup the integration with JazzID/Jazz Password, and then you have upgraded to IBM MobileFirst Platform Quality Assurance 6.3, then you need to re-configure the RTC setup with JazzID and IBM ID Password for the integration to work.

More information can be found in the Knowledge Center : [Integrating with Rational Team Concert](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFRDS_6.3.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.doc/topics/t_wi_integration.html)